# How can I use make_blobs with a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Machine Learning and trying to do some exercises to figure some stuff out.

I am reading a csv file into a dataframe as such:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path + "tweets.csv", header=None)
df.head()
```

I then want to use this data frame (which is really just all my data) to do a `train_test_split`. I was looking into it and found out that the way to do it is this:

```
# create dataset
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=500)
# split into train test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(n_samples, test_size=0.20)
print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)
```

However, I tried to make my dataset a `np_array` by doing `n_samples = df.to_numpy()` before the `make_blobs` method, however, when I try to do this I get the following error:

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)

I thought it was because the variable wasn't big enough but it is. So I'm a bit lost. I understand that it's expecting to be able to get 4 values out but only receiving 2, however, I took the code straight from [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html), so I guess I'm missing something or I'm misunderstanding.

Could someone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: What _is_ `make_blobs`?

Comment: @AKX. `from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem, you have to provide a sample of your dataframe.

For your dataframe, you need to determine which columns are data (X) and which columns are labels (y)

```
X_cols = ['feat1', 'feat2', 'feat3']
y_cols = ['label']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = \
    train_test_split(df[X_cols], df[y_cols], test_size=0.2)
```

At the end of the operation:

- `X_train` has 80% of `df[X_cols]`
- `X_test` has 20% of `df[X_cols]`
- `y_train` has 80% of `df[y_cols]`
- `y_test` has 20% of `df[y_cols]`

**Update**

If you want to use the data created by `make_blob`, use:

```
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=500)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just one question, when would one use `make_blobs()` then?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have only provided one input array to `train_test_split` which means it just splits this array into 2 depending on the testing ratio. In the example given in the docs, there are two inputs to `train_test_split` (X and y) and the function splits each of them into two arrays (resulting in 4 values).

The sklearn function knows nothing about the arrays being provided. It randomly splits as many arrays as you provide into 2 arrays (train and test) depending on the ratio provided while guaranteeing that the order in which the rows are split is same for each array (i.e. you maintain the taining data, its labels, and any other metadata you have for the same in other arrays).